# How to do google login in Expressjs using JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using JSON web token for my authentication

here is the flow:-

1. Client: Enter your email and password into the login form.
2. Client: Send a POST request to /login
3. Server: Check if email exists, if not -return 401.
4. Server: Check if password is correct,Create a JSON Web Token and
     send it back to the client.

Based on that token I am doing further operations,lets say creating a post,contact etc..
All me API's are secured with the JWT,if the token is valid then only I can perform any operations.

Now I am generating the Google oauth token with this [library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)
and sending access_token(given by google) to client

Now how should I do other operations with this google access token ??should I store google user info in my user collection again ?if yes then how ? what should be in password field ?

or

Is this whole flow is wrong ?

Comment: You cant use login and password with Google Auth anymore.    I am not sure what you are using the JWT for but you can use the access token to access the Google APIs as normal.    If you want to validate the access token you need to make sure you are requesting the openId scope and then you can validate the token_id that is returned it is a jwt.

Comment: You may want to tag this google-oauth to get more attention but I am not sure which tag to remove express or mongoose

Comment: I am generating jwt for my custom users..in my mongoose collection i m storing username & password...and if the login is sucessfull..m giving back token with payloads...so that they can make other api calls.....so ijust go a thought..as soon as i am generating google auth token..i can make google user api call on server itself..and generate the jwt..with new payload....